# Are the following two ways of returning an C++ object doing the same?

Tags: c++

Suppose a function that create a class and return:

```
Foo getFoo ()
{
   return Foo ("bar");
}
```

And second method:

```
Foo getFoo ()
{
   Foo foo ("bar");
   return foo;
}
```

Now I call it with `const Foo & myFoo = getFoo()`

Is the first method more efficient? They looked same to me, since they both create a temp variable and returns it, am I wrong?

Comment: Also consider `return {"bar"};` in C++11.

Comment: @sftrabbit Only if Foo's constructor is not `explicit`

Comment: @sftrabbit: Clever trick; but not a good idea. Being explicit will make the code easier to read and maintain for future coders.

Comment: @LokiAstari I meant consider it also when answering the question, not for the asker to consider it for his/her code! Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're basically the same, although copy elision in the first one would be called 'return value optimization' (RVO) while in the second it would be 'named return value optimization' (NRVO). At one point there were compilers that could do RVO but not NRVO.

Comment: It may also depend on the level of optimization, for example I seem to remember than MSVC would not perform NRVO in debug builds.